# Running Apple DocC as a Apple Help Book file

Tags: swift, macos, documentation-generation, docc

With the introduction of DocC for generating documentation from source code, is it possible to take the output of DocC and use it as the source of truth for an Apple Help Book (for use inside of a macOS App)?

- DocC Introduction: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10166/
- Apple Help Book for Mac Apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEHEAC

Comment: @ElTomato The OP provided a link explaining what an Apple Help Book is. If that's not a familiar topic to you, then it's not a familiar topic to you.

Comment: How do you go from DocC to Help Book or Help Desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to take the output of DocC and use it as the source of truth for an Apple Help Book?

- Yes, but likely **not worth it**.

---

**@matt** mentioned:

> A DocC is a highly restricted, formalized representation of a very specific type of information.

However I disagree with it. You can create article pages with DocC: [Getting Started with Sloths](https://xcode-docc.netlify.app/documentation/slothcreator/gettingstarted)

---

The **problems** with using DocC to create Apple Help Book:

- DocC documentation only support basic markdown syntax, so your formatting option is limited.
- DocC exports the documentation as a single page web app, where Apple Help Book expect individual html files for each help pages. So you would need to automatically generate static html files.
- DocC documentation doesn't let you add custom meta tags for indexing or keywords and name for anchors. (Maybe you can use comments in markdown, then automatically generate them from comments. However I'm not sure if comments in markdown would remain in DocC generated file)
- You would still need to use Help Indexer to index them.

---

**@matt** mentioned:

> A help book helps users, whereas DocC displays a programming API to a programmer.

You can definitely meld the two and use DocC generated files as your source of truth, but I would rather do it with **other html editors**, or a **better markdown editor** if you prefer the markdown syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, it's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. They are completely different animals. A help book is a complete web site with some help for certain kinds of anchors. A DocC is a highly restricted, formalized representation of a very specific type of information. Indeed, even if you meld the two things, you would not want to; a help book helps users, whereas DocC displays a programming API to a programmer.

Just as an example, here is a help book I wrote:

http://www.apeth.com/sd5help/index.html

You couldn't possibly express that using DocC. If the problem is that you're looking for a tool to help you write help books, DocC is not it.